# What does the Dress Module do?

Tags: nier-automata

I bought from Emil's Shop outside the Resistance Camp an item called the Dress Module. Its icon in the menu is that of a curtain and when I use it, I see the same curtain I see when I equip a costume (like the DLC ones).

I used it as A2 and it didn't seem to do anything aside from add a curtain icon under my health bar. I've read places that

> [the] dress module prevents clothing damage normally if you hit critical her skirt is broken/skimpier but not GONE like if you self destruct. module prevents that

[Source: Gamefaqs - Shybaason - Post #3](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75094992)

but I've never seen any clothing damage aside from cutscenes, to when used with A2

> Leaves her in only her bra and g-string

[Source: Gamefaqs - ukokira1 - Post #7](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75206730)

which I don't recall seeing, in fact it still looked like she was wearing her same torn up stuff (if it makes a difference here (because in some games it does) I brought my game from OzGameShop, so it's probably a UK Release).

What does the Dress Module do? If there is an appearance change, screenshots would be appreciated for all 3 characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The confusion seems to be coming from the fact that the sources you've linked say that clothing gets damaged as you do. Your clothing only really gets damaged when you self-destruct. As A2, you cannot do this, so the Dress Module will not affect her.

The Dress Module only does anything for 2B and 9S and prevents them from losing their clothes when they self-destruct. 2B loses her entire skirt, while 9S loses his pants when self-destructing without the Dress Module. To illustrate this, I made a couple videos:

Answer (score 0):

When you don't wear the dress module, your clothing gets damaged as you sustain heavy damage. It's most obvious when you use self-destruct as it blows your skirt/pants away. With the module on, your costume never takes any damage.